# Laravel public URL for locally Uploaded File

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have uploaded a publicly accessible file to my local disk. I can see it in my IDE at storage/app/public/mysubdir/myfile.js.
I have run the artisan command to create a symlink to the public directory. And I can also see the file at public/storage/mysubdir/myfile.js.
Yet when I go to http://my.app/storage/mysubdir/myfile.js I get the error "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179".

Any ideas? Do I need to add some special route? Or update Nginx?

I have followed https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files and https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk

Cheers

Comment: Do you have any route point to **/storage**?

Comment: No. Not as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem. I originally ran `php artisan storage:link` on my local machine rather than in the virtual machine. I deleted the symlink and re-ran `php artisan storage:link` inside Vagrant/Homestead and then it started working.

Answer (score 0):

be sure to store file publicly like this:

```
$request->file('file')->store('images', 'public');
```

and restore it something like that:

```
asset('storage/file.ext');
```

to know more:

- [Storing files in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files)
- [FileSystem: Prepare public disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: I have done a similar thing. I am doing `$file->storePubliclyAs(Auth::id(), $file->getClientOriginalName(), ['disk' => 'public']);` along with `asset(Storage::url($file))`

Comment: write here one of the image path saved in DB and also try **asset('storage/'.$model->image_path_saved_in_db)**

Answer (score 0):

Please check my code upload image to store in public folder work on both local and server side

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request){
        $file =  Input::file('image'); 
        if(empty($file)){
            return Response()->json(['error' => "Image is required" ], 406);
        }
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
            $filename = rand(11111111111,999999999999).'.'.$extension; 
            $tmp_path = public_path('users/thumbnail/');
            $letmovefiles   = $file->move($tmp_path, $filename);
            $full = $tmp_path.$filename;
            $destinationPath = public_path('users/');
            if ($_FILES['image']) {
                $image   = Image::make($full);
                $image->resize(600, 600)->save();
                $new_path = $destinationPath;
              rename($destinationPath,$new_path);  
            }
          $getlnik = url('users/thumbnail').'/'.$filename;
         return Response()->json(['url' => $getlnik ], 200);
    }
```

Comment: It looks as though you're storing your files in the public directory. How would that work with zero down-time deployments?